# Split string into List<int> ignore none int values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string

Am using the following code to split a string into a List<int>, however occasionally the string includes non integer values, which are handled differently.

An example string might be like: 1,2,3,4,x

code looks like:

```
List<int> arrCMs = new List<int>(strMyList.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)));
```

The problem is as soon as it hits the 'x' it throws an error because 'x' can't be parsed as an integer.

How can I make it ignore non integer values? I'm sure I should be able to do something with int.TryParse but can't quite figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
List<int> arrCMs = strMyList.Split(',')
    .Select(possibleIntegerAsString => {
        int parsedInteger = 0;
        bool isInteger = int.TryParse(possibleIntegerAsString , out parsedInteger);
        return new {isInteger, parsedInteger};
    })
    .Where(tryParseResult => tryParseResult.isInteger)
    .Select(tryParseResult => tryParseResult.parsedInteger)
    .ToList();
```

The first `Select` in the above example returns an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) that describes the result of [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - that is, whether it was a valid integer, and if so, what the value was.

The `Where` clause filters out those that weren't valid.

The second `Select` then retrieves the parsed values from the strings that were able to be parsed.

Comment: Nice, though I think Andrew's answer is slightly nicer.

Answer (score 7):

Short and sweet, using `int.TryParse`:

```
List<int> nums = list
    .Split(',')
    .Select(i => 
    { 
        int val;
        return int.TryParse(i, out val) ? (int?)val : null;
    })
    .Where(i => i.HasValue)
    .Cast<int>()
    .ToList()
```

**Working Example:** http://dotnetfiddle.net/4wyoAM

Comment: +1 for not using anonymous types when you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
int result;
List<int> arrCMs =
            new List<int>(strMyList.Split(',')
                                    .Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out result))
                                    .Select(int.Parse));
```

Comment: You forgot the `out` keyword.

Comment: Also, casting a string to int will fail.

Comment: Nice solution, but it has poor performances since you end up parsing twice.

Answer (score 0):

another one, using `Array.ForEach`

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();
Array.ForEach(strMyList.Split(','), s =>
    {
        int i;
        if (int.TryParse(s, out i)){ ints.Add(i);}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Plot twist: use an old-school `foreach` loop.

```
List<int> arrCMs = new List<int>();
foreach (string str in strMyList.Split(new [] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    int res;
    if (int.TryParse(str, out res))
    {
        arrCMs.Add(res);
    }
}
```

You could also create a method for it and make use of an iterator block by using `yield return`:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ParseIntegers(string val, char seperator = ',')
{
    foreach (string str in val.Split(new [] { seperator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        int res;
        if (int.TryParse(str, out res))
        {
            yield return res;
        }
    }
}
```

This is probably over-engineering if it's only for one time use.

Answer (score -1):

Parse once only for each value, but a bit tricky.

```
int result = 0;
List<int> arrCMs = strMyList.Split(',')
                            .Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out result))
                            .Select(x => result)
                            .ToList();
```